# JQuery cross slide stick top left in Firefox

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-plugins, slideshow

I am using JQuery [CrossSlide](http://tobia.github.com/CrossSlide/) plugin in my site.
It all works fine in Chrome and IE but in Firefox all the slides in the page are
sticking to the top left corner.

You can see the problem here : [My Site](http://www.tmunaledorot.co.il/Products.aspx)

It would be great if anyone can point me to the solution of this issue.

Thanks a lot,
Elad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your images in a DIV tag

```
<div class="product_image" style="overflow: hidden; padding: 0px; position: relative ! important;">
    <img ..../>
    <img ..../>
</div>
```

You can also put your table in position: relative

Comment: Thanks for you answer but when I added the div tag the slide show stopped working. you can see it now in [my site](http://www.tmunaledorot.co.il/Products.aspx)

Comment: There is no images anymore, make sure crossslide is called on the right elements

Comment: Hi Philippe, after I tried your solution I saw some errors in the developer tool and it said that I was missing definition of width and height in the slideshow container. Once I added the attributes everything work like a charm. Thanks a lot for you help

Answer (score 0):

It's due to table cells not being able to properly contain absolutely positioned elements.  Your slider is absolutely positioned, and it is within a  element.

To solve this, you can wrap the slider in a div that is position: relative;, which will then give the slider the ability to remain absolutely positioned in the cell.

Comment: Thanks for you answer but when I added the div tag the slide show stopped working. you can see it now in [my site](http://www.tmunaledorot.co.il/Products.aspx)